# What communication protocol would you recommend?

Tags: .net, client-server, protocols

I'm about to design a client application and the server part is not designed either.

I need to decide on the communication protocol.

The requirements are:

- fast, compact
- supports binary file transfer both ways
- server is probably PHP, client .NET

So far I have considered these:

- custom XML over HTTP - I've done this in the past, but it's not very suitable for file transfer, otherwise OK
- SOAP - no experience, I read it's very verbose and complicated
- Google protobuf - read a lot of good things about this
- pure HTTP - using get and post - this may be badly extensible.

I'm open to suggestions. So far i'm leaning towards protobuf.

**Edit: More info**

- The server will be data heavy, thin application layer, possibly only database itself. Milions to a billion records, search intensive (fultext and custom searches).
- Expected client application count is in hundeds, but may grow
- 2 types of messages from server to client, small (under 100KB), but very common, large (file downloads, under 10MB cca)
- client sends back only the smaller messages but with more information.
- i'd like to have information structured, to provide meta information both ways.
- i'd like it extensible for future changes
- Encryption mandatory (considering https as transport layer)
- Lantency is crutial, I'd like to achieve "standard" web latencies (under 200ms would be good), for the small messages. This really depends on many things.

Comment: Seems like straing TCP fits your bill, no?

Comment: No it doesn't TCP is not an application communication protocol. I'ts a transfer protocol.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to make an informed decision here. Give details of your use case, expected communication patterns, latency requirements, deployment scenarios, who the parties are, etc.; otherwise you'll just get advice as to what people personally prefer / think is cool, rather than what's appropriate for you.

Comment: @Mark Nottingham see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use simple HTTP, TCP (with sockets) or FTP, unless your really need some more sofisticated functionalities

Comment: I sort need some meta information, so FTP is out of question. TCP is transport protocol I would need to roll my own definition.

Comment: I accepted this, because I decided to start as simple as possible. I use https GET and POST with xml if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well protocol buffers certainly work well for us :)

You may well want to layer them over HTTP though. Obviously you'll need *some* sort of transport layer between TCP/IP and protocol buffers themselves - protobufs don't define anything other than serialized messages. HTTP is generally well understood, goes through firewalls easily, and has both client and server support on multiple platforms.

One concern: I'm not sure what sort of protocol buffer support there is in PHP. There's a [beta library here](http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/), but that's all I could see listed in the [3rd party add-ons page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when using HTTP, the server cannot send information to the client without a request, so you'll probably have to use a technique similar to long-polling.

I wanted to add this as a comment but I'm not able to do it.

Comment: That is fine, that's why I mentioned server-client.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Protocol Buffers sounds like a great choice.  That is pretty much what it was designed for.

The .NET port is written by none other than Jon Skeet:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/

I am not sure how great the support in PHP is though.  That could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend protocol buffers, over TCP. HTTP should be avoided unless you go with a higher-level abstraction that implicitly uses HTTP.

The .NET port of protocol buffers AFAIK does not support asynchronous reading of the protobuffers, so I'd recommend using asynchronous sockets and use length-prefixed protobuffers.

I've written several recommendations for protocol design on my [.NET TCP/IP FAQ](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html), including XML over TCP/IP (I do agree that XML is not a good fit for your needs, though).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use HTTP for one of your common message types, the "large" (but <10MB) binary, that might prove too slow for your applications.  But testing will show it anything HTTP-based is acceptable for your use cases.  So maybe use FTP for the large binary messages, and whatever else for the small messages.  Yes, I am recommending that you use two types of communication protocols here.